# Is it possible to get userid and name of a logged user from iframe fan page/landing page?

Tags: facebook

How could i get the userid and name of a user who's visiting my facebook page or atleast after like my page? I've created a fan-gate i.e. one page for not fans and another page for those who liked my page. I wanted to display Thank you Mr. ABC

for fan gate mechanism I have used signed request.

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
   list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);

    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

$liked=0;
if ($_REQUEST) {
    $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],                       FACEBOOK_SECRET);
    $liked=$response[page][liked];
}
```

I can understand that Facebook disallows to access user information from page itself. But as I believe javascript and jquery are client side scripts and using this i could be able to fullfill my requirements. Eventhough I had no luck being success, the idea behind my concept is to access certain tag/selector and retrieve the content inside of parent window of facebook page frame container. i.e.

1. creating a jquery script to access parent window
2. Facebook's top menu contains small image thumbnail and Full Name of logged in user
3. using jquery's tag selector to retrieve the content of that html tag

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  You would have to create an application and prompt the user for permissions to access their account.  Liking a page alone is not sufficient to figure out who the user is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer to my question and shared [here](http://prajwaladhikari.com.np/wp/accessing-name-username-gender-and-profile-id-on-your-landing-page_on_prajwals_blog/). Make it useful for you also.